# Massive update with where clause with calculated value for each row?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 400.000 rows and I added a new column on it. That table has an index id and I want to update each row with a different value that I have already calculated.
For example, I have the update statements like these:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET SECOND_NAME = 'Alfred' WHERE id = 510675;
UPDATE TABLE SET SECOND_NAME = 'Pedro' WHERE id = 123123;
UPDATE TABLE SET SECOND_NAME = 'Robert' WHERE id = 123123;
```

SECOND_NAME is the new column that I want to populate, lets say I have around 400.000 update statements, is there a way to massive update them in a faster way? If not, is there a way to know beforehand how long it could take to update them in that way?

Comment: Store the pairs in a table and use a lookup into that table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I hope I understood correctly, I should create like a table with the values id and second_name and make an insert statement for the 400.000 rows and then try to update/merge into the table that I want to update using the created table?

Comment: . . In my experience, a list of 400,000 such changes would already be in the database.  If not, I would load it from a file.  But you can choose whatever method seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet, is probably to use an EXTERNAL TABLE.  This AskTom answer basically gives you everything you need: [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:70109473088345).  However, to customize it for your question.  You could take the information you have, save it to a CSV and load it in as follows.

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_names (id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY, second_name VARCHAR2(50))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(type oracle_loader
 default directory data_dir
 access parameters ( fields terminated by ',' )
 location ('names.csv')
)
/

UPDATE (SELECT t.second_name empty_name, n.second_name loaded_name
        FROM table_name t
        INNER JOIN new_names n ON t.id = n.id)
SET empty_name = loaded_name;
/
```

All you need to do to make that work is create the directory and place your file in it.
After you are done, you can drop the the external table.